# Mobx4 - declaring observable in store throwing a sintax error

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, create-react-app, mobx

According to the [migration guide from mobx](https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx/wiki/Migrating-from-mobx-3-to-mobx-4), this is the correct way to assign observables now (the `...` stand for other, irrelevant code):

```
class BaseMapsStore {
  uiStore = null
  mapStore = null
  datesStore = null
  selectedBaseMap = "OSM"
  baseMapOptions = ["Sentinel", "OSM", "None"]
  layers = null
  ...
}

export default decorate(BaseMapsStore, {
  uiStore: observable,
  mapStore: observable,
  datesStore: observable,
  selectedBaseMap: observable,
  baseMapOptions: observable,
  layers: observable,
  ...
});
```

But using create-react-app I am getting the following error:
Failed to compile.

Failed to compile.

```
./src/stores/BaseMapsStore/BaseMapsStore.js
Syntax error: Unexpected token (12:10)

  10 | 
  11 | class BaseMapsStore {
> 12 |   uiStore = null
     |           ^
  13 |   mapStore = null
  14 |   datesStore = null
  15 |   selectedBaseMap = "OSM"
```

Do I need a babel plugin in order to make this work? What is the exact syntax error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Class fields](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields) are stage 3 proposal.

Babel [`preset-stage-3`](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-stage-3/) (or lower) is required to use them.

[`transform-decorators`](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-decorators/) plugin is also required to make MobX work.